# VSIX is not installed on experimental instance when debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility

I have a VSIX solution in VS 2019 targeting 2015, 2017, and 2019.
The solution builds fine, and I can install it manually using the .vsix file. It installs fine on all targeted versions of VS.

But, when I try to debug it in VS2019 targeting 2015 or 2017, the experimental instance of the target version opens up but the extension is not installed on it!

I searched on google for days, and I can't find anything!

Comment: Could you please share more detailed info to describe your issue? The vsix project is installed under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\Extensions\xxx(vs username)`

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT

The question is pretty much says it all really! What more details you want to know?

Comment: If you can debug the vsix project which targets to VS2015 or VS2017, it hints that the extension is installed on your current vs experimental instance. When you debug the project, enter the experimental vs instance, `Extensions`-->`Manage Extensions`-->`Installled`, check whether your extension is installed. In my VS2019, I modify the `source.extension.vsixmanifest` file, change `Install Target` to `[14.0, 16.0)`, then start debugging, I can see that extension is installed on  the experimental instance.

Comment: So if you are still face the issue, please try to close your project, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin` and `obj` folder. Then, restart your project to test again. Please let us know if you follow the same steps just as I described. If not, please feel free to let us know. And let us know if my suggestion works. If not, we will provide further suggestions for you.

Comment: I am on VS2022 targeting VS2022 and had the same problem. Following the suggestion provided by @MrQian to delete the .vs, bin, and obj folders worked in my case.